# How to get wifi working on Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless

I am new to Linux.  Just installed Ubuntu 12.10.  I can get a wired internet connection but cannot get a wireless connection.  Can anybody help?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you have the driver enabled for your wireless card. In order to do this, go to settings>software sources>additional drivers. You may need to temporarily use a wired connection to activate the driver.

Answer (score 2):

> ## Connect to a wireless network
>
> If you have a wireless-enabled computer,
> you can connect to a wireless network that is within range to get
> access to the internet, view shared files on the network, and so on.
>
> 1. If you have a wireless hardware switch on your computer, make sure
>    that it is turned on.
> 2. Click the network menu in the menu bar, and click the name of the
>    network you want to connect to. If the name of the network isn't in the list, select More Networks to
>    see if the network is further down the list. If you still don't see
>    the network, you may be out of range or the network [might be hidden](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-hidden.html).
> 3. If the network is protected by a password ([encryption key](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-wepwpa.html)), enter the
>    password when prompted and click Connect. If you do not know the key, it may be written on the underside of the wireless router or base station, in its instruction manual, or you may have to ask the person who administers the wireless network.
> 4. The network icon will change appearance as the computer attempts to
>    connect to the network.
> 5. If the connection is successful, the icon will change to a dot with
>    several bars above it. More bars indicate a stronger connection to the
>    network. If there aren't many bars, the connection is weak and might
>    not be very reliable.
>
> If the connection is not successful, you [may be asked for your
> password again](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-help/net-passwordok-noconnect.html) or it might just tell you that the connection has been
> disconnected. There are a number of things that could have caused this
> to happen. You could have entered the wrong password, the wireless
> signal could be too weak, or your computer's wireless card might have
> a problem, for example. See [Wireless network troubleshooter](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html) for more
> help.
>
> A stronger connection to a wireless network does not necessarily mean
> that you have a faster internet connection, or that you will have
> faster download speeds. The wireless connection connects your computer
> to the device which provides the internet connection (like a router or
> modem), but the two connections are actually different, and so will
> run at different speeds.

From: [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-connect.html)

Comment: Thank you.  However on Ubuntu 12.10 I cannot see the wireless network at all.  I know the network is working as I have other devices connected to it.  It will not detect any networks at all.